# ASP.NET Core configure method doesn't end early?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httprequest, endpoint, static-files

I was taught that the concept of pipeline routing in ASP.NET Core 3+ means, when a request comes in, it gets handled by the first available method (between `app.UseRouting` and `app.UseEndPoints` in `Startup.cs`) which can deal with it.

If it can't handle it, it passes it on to the next function.

If so, say I have an `index.html` in my `wwwroot` folder, I would expect it to be returned when I navigate to root (`/`)

I have included the method `app.UseFileServer`.

However, this is not the case. Rather I get back "hello world".

Only if I change the `endpoints.MapGet` to a more unique path, only then I will get my `index.html` returned.

Below is the (simple) code:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseFileServer();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
                });
            });
```

Was I taught wrong?

Does every request go through every method?

Comment: I believe to handle static files like `index.html`, you need to use `app.UseStaticFiles()` - not `UseFileServer` . See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0   But most likely, if you enter just `/` as your URL, this will be handled by some MVC route - I suspect you'd have to enter `/index.html` explicitly to get ASP.NET Core to render the `index.html` static file

Comment: @marc_s Can you explain. UseFileServer is just a shortcut for useStaticFiles and useDefaultFiles. (A quick google search shows this). Also, like I wrote in the question, When i change mapGet to anything but the root (like /hello), I do get returned index.html from root

Comment: OK - thanks for clarifying - I found this explanation in the meantime, too ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0) . But in all those samples I see, typically, `UseFileServer` (and `UseHttpsRedirection`) would be referenced **before** `UseRouting` - can you try that?

Comment: +1. Thanks that worked. Would you know why it has to be before UseRouting. And why afterwords, it behaves weirdly.

Comment: Hey Joe - no, I don't know that off the top of my head - I'm sure if you dig long enough, you'll find some blog post or article about it somewhere.... I just kept seeing all those samples in the MS docs that always have the static file middlewares configured *before* the routing - and I believe if you see several examples all showing the same sequence - it's probably like that for a good reason ;-)

Comment: Yes your right. I am reading the book C# 9 and .NET 5 by Mark J. Price and on page 499, he has UseDefaultFiles and UseStaticFiles after UseRouting. Thanks again